# PHP:file_get_contents() Error

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

I am using file_get_contents to read json data.

My code is :

```
   //echo $json_url;
    $json_data = file_get_contents($json_url);
```

I am surprise that, the variable $json_data returns null value.
When I echo the variable $json_url, it displays the correct url. Tt also displays json record when I manually enter the url in browser.

What can be error here?

Comment: Do you get an error message? If you cant see an error message then did you configure PHP to display error messages?

Comment: is it an API request? if yes, did you meed every precondition?

Answer (score 1):

What is the URL?

> [Note:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)
>
> If you're opening a URI with special characters, such as spaces, you need to encode the URI with urlencode().

Furthermore, are url fopen wrappers enabled?

> [Tip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)
>
> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the [fopen wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) have been enabled.

But you will see why the request failed if you [enable error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php).

Comment: my url structure is http://localhost/jsread.p?call=favo&user=&lang=en&tree=1266&sort=last&max=500&startpage=1&pagesize=20 
I am using codeigniter framework. When I manually my actual url in browser, it displays record.

Comment: I still get null values in array.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im , its not API. Database is in Progress. So to access it, I am using URL which send me data in JSON format.

Comment: @nppCods Then start debugging. What does `var_dump(file_get_contents($json_url));` print?

Answer (score 0):

Try to [urlencode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the url first

```
$json_data = file_get_contents(urlencode($json_url));
```

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im I never heard of that too, but (as you can see in my answer) it is required when your URL contains "special characters".

Comment: From PHP Manual: If you're opening a URI with special characters, such as spaces, you need to encode the URI with urlencode().

Comment: No it won't work. It will simply convert a valid URL into an invalid one e.g. `http://does-not-require-encoding/file.json` to `http%3A%2F%2Fdoes-not-require-encoding%2Ffile.json`.